# What is a word for "giving more meaning to something than it deserves?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Or something that tries to convey more meaning to you than it deserves to.

It's an adjective similar to "condescending."

I'm almost certain the word starts with an "e."

Comment: *Overrate, overvalue, overestimate?* It might depend what exactly you mean by *meaning*. There's always [***overweening***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Overween), suitable for describing *people* who think they "mean" too much.

Comment: *Overanalyze*, perhaps?

Comment: Because of the leading "e", "exacerbate" ? Definition: to increase the severity, bitterness, or violence of (disease, ill feeling, etc.); aggravate.

Comment: *emphasize* ... ?

Comment: *credulity*? *credulousness*? Too much *credence*? *Overcredit*?

Comment: The idiom "reading more into it than it deserves" is fairly common.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, that first occurred to me upon reading the title, but  'reading more into it' is about something that a recipient of a message might do, while the body of the question indicates that the word is about something that its author might do. (It is difficult to be sure what precisely that is, so the question is unanswerable.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for **exaggerated**?

> adjective
>
> 1.unduly or unrealistically magnified

(dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

The adjectives, **embroidered** or **embellished**, may convey what you intend. These come from the verbs:

> **embroider** *v.tr.*
>   3. To add embellishments or fanciful details to ....
>
> *v.intr.*
>   2. To add embellishments or fanciful details.

[embroider. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 6 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/embroider .]

Something 'embroidered' has also been 'embellished':

> **embellish** *tr.v.*
>   2. To add ornamental or fictitious details to ....

[embellish. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 6 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/embellish .]

If you find yourself in need of a noun, **embroidery** is the noun form of the one, and **embellishment** the other.